# String allinging

Tags: java, format

If I want my output string to be at least 5 digits long I can use for example `System.out.printf("'%5d'", 10)`, but can I substitute 5 with some variable which contain the string length? Or what should I use for my output to be as long as X?

Comment: Probably, my bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Just use a variable in the format string:

```
int length = 50;
System.out.printf("'%"+length+"d'", 10);
```

Output:

```
'                                                10'
```